# Ionic firebase specify google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 project and I wanted to add firebase to the project.

I installed the firebase cordova plugin and placed my google-services.json in `resources/android` but I get an error while parsing google-services.json : `No matching client found for package name [name here]`

When I look at my google-services.json that I put in `resources/android` the package name is correct but when I look in `platforms/android` the file is completely different and the package name is `com.github.cordova_plugin_firebase`

Anyone know how can make sure the correct google-services.json is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this steps.

1. first remove your android platform to your project using **ionic cordova platform remove android**
2. copy google-services.json file to the root directory (where package.json/config.xml file).
3. then try to add android platoform using **ionic cordova platform add android**.then check your android folder google-services.json file copied automatically,if not then copy it to the android folder.
4. Then check your build.gradle fileto include the google-services
   plugin and the  Google's Maven repository:

   ```
   buildscript{
      //add dependencies as per your google-service version
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin 
    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
          google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
   }
   ```
5. Then, in your module Gradle file (app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    }

   // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

**Note:If you are using codova-android >= 7, you now must add**

```
 <platform name="android">
     <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
 </platform>
```

Comment: Where is that google-services.json coming from? What's in it?

Comment: For someone who is interested, google-services.json can be created from Firebase, adding a new Android app for you project.

Comment: I am trying to generate an android apk.but I have a problem . The roblem is when I try to build the application  , I shows me an error the google-services.json can't be found. Can someone please tell me where can I find it??