# Unable to overwrite google-services.json with the one downloaded from firebase + ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm creating a sample hybrid app ( for ios and android ) using ionic cordova. I have added both android and ios to the project. When I tried to replace existing google-services.json with the one that I download from firebase, after building the project the file resets to default one ( doesn't change to overwritten one). I have tried to add json file to both project level folder and app level folder but the issue is same. 
ionic version - 4.10.3
cordova - 8.1.2
node - 10.15.1

Comment: where did you put your google-services.json file and why do you want to put it?

Comment: Issue is solved, I have placed the json file in root project folder and it worked.

Comment: okay, If you find any issue regarding google-serivces.json file then check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542694/ionic-firebase-specify-google-services-json/54547734#54547734 ,I have explained it step by step how to implement it.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just add my google-services.json file in the android & android/app folder and my issue is fixed