# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. when run ionic cordova build android

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-services

When I run a command "ionic cordova build android", i have error like this:

```
 * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'ammar_5d767'
```

I have already try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54547734) steps however still not working. 
here is my  config.xml

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="ammar-5d767" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Doc.in</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
<platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
.
.
.
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
.
.
.
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
.
.
.
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="2.0.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

i found some solutions but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Googleservice.json file is missing from the project folder which can be found in firebase console.